# Windows Service doesn't complete what it's intended to do and it's suddenly stopped by the system?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, pdf, windows-services

I've been stuck with this annoying problem for the last couple of hours, and I've just exhausted my resources. This is what's going on:

I have a Windows Service created using the 4.0 .NET framework.  The main functionality of this service is to read all .txt files contained in a folder, validate the formatting of these files and then send them to another folder, create an xml file from those files, and then create a pdf file using the information contained in the xml; I'm using the Report.NET library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/report/) to create these .pdf files.

When I run the service, it does everything it's supposed to do except generate the .pdf file, and then I get the following error:

"Service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some service stop automatically if they have no work to do."

Also, I forgot to mention, if I debug the windows service using Visual Studio, everything works as intended and the .pdf files are generated correctly.

I've already tried attaching the "main" function to a thread and then starting that thread on the OnStart() method, but that doesn't seem to work, neither adding a timer.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Sounds like an exception might be occurring.

Comment: Check Windows Event log for exception in your service.

Comment: Put a try-catch block in your thread function and write any exceptions to the Windows event log.  Off the cuff, you might have a path problem (or something similar) that only shows itself when you run outside the debugger.

Comment: I actually did tried that, it says that i have a  "null-reference exception" when the application reaches the "createPDF" method which is odd, i tried the same code on a console application and it is working properly.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12209075/909742) post?

Comment: So...i just added a timer and captured the process in a try-catch block and now it's working properly. That's odd, that's just the way i had it originally:

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
           // if (args[0] == "DEBUG") { Debugger.Launch(); }
            Timer time;
            time = new Timer();
            time.Interval = 5000;
            try
            {
                 time.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoYaThing);
                 time.Start();
               
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                
       }}

Comment: Code working differently if you put in a delay is a symptom of a race condition.