# Self Hosting OWIN in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, owin

With legacy .NET, you could [self-host OWIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) via the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost/).

Is there a way to self-host OWIN in a .NET Core console app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527257/host-web-api-as-windows-service-using-owin

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, use the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin/) Package.

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 1):

As of **.Net 6 Preview**, the package to load, as mentioned, is *still* a **preview** package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin`.

It is best to use the example found on the docs [Open Web Interface for .NET (OWIN) with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which references this github package of examples [OwinSample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/owin/sample/src/OwinSample).

The sample given is more involved that the original OWIN readme one; but it works.

Comment: FYI to others - the versioning of core.Owin mirrors the .net version it targets.  .6x owin targets .net6, 2.x owin targets .net standard 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

OWIN basically provides decoupling between the web server and web application.In the case of .NET core you need to use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin package.After you add this nuget you can access the OwinExtensions class which consists of extension methods related to OWIN.One method you could use is UseOwin().These methods are defined in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin assembly.

OWIN compatible server such as [NOWIN](https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin) can also host ASP.NET Core applications.